# Do I have enough information to reproject this image?

Tags: gdal

I have been working with weather data and have 2 GeoTIFFs. One of them was generated with the correct projection, but the other was produced by a program that did not project the data.  I would like to use the image with the correct projection and apply it to the unprojected image using GDAL. Do I have enough information to reproject the image to match the other's projection, and if so - how can I do it? The unprojected image looks like just points of data when I used gdalinfo.

The image that has the correct projection is "base.tif", the other is "target.tif". Here is the gdalinfo on both images.

*I have added Google Drive links to both files below this information.*

**Base.tif** :

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: base.tif
Size is 1000, 849
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-100.622518596428350,31.882826288864834)
Pixel Size = (0.005187037192857,-0.005189664368550)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=nc2geotiff
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Warning 1: TIFFFetchNormalTag:incorrect count for field "PageNumber", expected 2, got 1
Warning 1: TIFFFetchNormalTag:Incompatible type for "GDALNoDataValue"; tag ignored
Warning 1: TIFFFetchNormalTag:incorrect count for field "PageNumber", expected 2, got 1
Warning 1: TIFFFetchNormalTag:Incompatible type for "GDALNoDataValue"; tag ignored
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=GTIFF_DIR:1:base.tif
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=Page 1 (1000P x 849L x 1B)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=GTIFF_DIR:2:base.tif
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=Page 2 (1000P x 849L x 1B)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-100.6225186,  31.8828263) (100d37'21.07"W, 31d52'58.17"N)
Lower Left  (-100.6225186,  27.4768012) (100d37'21.07"W, 27d28'36.48"N)
Upper Right ( -95.4354814,  31.8828263) ( 95d26' 7.73"W, 31d52'58.17"N)
Lower Right ( -95.4354814,  27.4768012) ( 95d26' 7.73"W, 27d28'36.48"N)
Center      ( -98.0290000,  29.6798138) ( 98d 1'44.40"W, 29d40'47.33"N)
Band 1 Block=1000x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

**And target.tif** :

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: target.tif
Size is 1200, 720
Metadata:
  azimuth#long_name=azimuth angle in degrees: 0 = true north, 90 = east
  azimuth#units=degrees
  azimuth#_CoordinateAxisType=RadialAzimuth
  gate#long_name=Radial distance to the start of gate
  gate#units=meters
  gate#_CoordinateAxisType=RadialDistance
  NC_GLOBAL#cdm_data_type=RADIAL
  NC_GLOBAL#conventions=_Coordinates
  NC_GLOBAL#creator_name=NOAA/NWS
  NC_GLOBAL#creator_url=http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/radar/radarproducts.html
  NC_GLOBAL#data_max=27
  NC_GLOBAL#data_min=0
  NC_GLOBAL#DateCreated=2021-11-20T05:16:26Z
  NC_GLOBAL#Divider=-1
  NC_GLOBAL#ElevationNumber=1
  NC_GLOBAL#format=Level3/NIDS
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_max=31.76918
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_min=27.638819
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_max=-100.40897
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_min=-95.649033
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_vertical_max=233.47681
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_vertical_min=233.47681
  NC_GLOBAL#isRadial=1
  NC_GLOBAL#keywords=WSR-88D; NIDS
  NC_GLOBAL#keywords_vocabulary=SW
  NC_GLOBAL#naming_authority=NOAA/NCDC
  NC_GLOBAL#NumberOfMaps=0
  NC_GLOBAL#OperationalMode=1
  NC_GLOBAL#ProductStation=EWX
  NC_GLOBAL#ProductStationName=Austin/San Antonio/New Braun,TX,US
  NC_GLOBAL#RadarAltitude=233.4768
  NC_GLOBAL#RadarElevationNumber=5
  NC_GLOBAL#RadarLatitude=29.704
  NC_GLOBAL#RadarLongitude=-98.029
  NC_GLOBAL#SequenceNumber=103
  NC_GLOBAL#summary=Nexrad level 3 data are WSR-88D radar products.SW is a radial image of base spectrum width at tilt 1 and range 124 nm
  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_end=2021-11-20T05:14:39Z
  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_start=2021-11-20T05:14:39Z
  NC_GLOBAL#title=Nexrad Level 3 Data
  NC_GLOBAL#VolumeCoveragePatternName=35
  NC_GLOBAL#VolumeScanNumber=60
  SpectrumWidth#long_name=Base Spectrum Width
  SpectrumWidth#units=Knots
  SpectrumWidth#_CoordinateAxes=elevation azimuth gate rays_time latitude longitude altitude
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  720.0)
Upper Right ( 1200.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 1200.0,  720.0)
Center      (  600.0,  360.0)
Band 1 Block=1200x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=9.96920996838686905e+36
  Unit Type: Knots
  Metadata:
    long_name=Base Spectrum Width
    NETCDF_VARNAME=SpectrumWidth
    units=Knots
    _CoordinateAxes=elevation azimuth gate rays_time latitude longitude altitude
```

The target file was produced from radial radar data, and I do see "RadialAzimuth" listed in the gdalinfo output. I have a hunch that it will take a specialized program to convert the image to the projection that *base.tif* has, but I am not positive so I am asking here.

For absolute completeness, I am adding links to the actual GeoTIFF files.

[Base.tif (good projection)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AGyosJvf2vtM6-GEonfZgkp7BDihsUsV/view?usp=sharing)

[Target.tif (needs to be projected)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19QgCvzW2ghqvhecjJtKnx-M8lYP-w2l2/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Perhaps use [`gdal_edit.py`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html) to add georeferencing using the NetCDF NC_GLOBAL metadata.  `gdal_edit.py -a_ullr -95.649033 31.76918 -100.40897 27.638819 target.tif` seemed to put it in roughly the right place, but not sure if it's exactly right, the pixel size and centre are a bit off compared to base.tif.

Comment: I will look into this